# How do I estimate probability of someone having condition X

Tags: mathematical-statistics, approximate-inference, stochastic-approximation

There is a survey, which asks following question: do you know personally someone, who has condition X?

The result of the survey is percentage of people, who know someone

I want to use this survey to estimate percentage of people in the population, who have condition X.

How do I do this?

Comment: It would really help if you gave us some context with as many details as possible.

Comment: @user2974951 what kind of additional data would be relevant?

Comment: For ex., what kind of survey was this? How many people were in the survey? How did you select these people? What is this mysterious condition X? Is this condition X something that the surveyed people have a chance of knowing? How many people answered that they know someone with condition X?

Comment: Condition X is being killed or wounded in a war, people usually have good chance of knowing it, the survey has a few thousand respondents who were selected randomly and surveyed by phone

Comment: There's no hope of obtaining a precise estimate from such information.  What if everybody knows the same person who has condition X and they are the unique individual with that condition?  What if everybody has condition X but nobody is willing to reveal it even to good friends?

Comment: I upvoted the question and hope it is preserved as an instructive example of what is probably not realistic to achieve with statistics.  And even then it is possible someone out there has devised a neat trick for addressing such research questions.  Perhaps something in the same spirit as the randomized response technique, though I'm not saying it would be the same technique.

Comment: There are many ways some condition X might influence the probability someone knows a person with the condition (up or down). You would either need to be able to rule that out, or to model its effect.